# How do I convince ggplot2 to create a legend for me?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've managed to get ggplot2 to create almost the plot I want from a data set, but I can't figure out how to label my points.

Given data looking something like this:

```
sample <- data.frame(rowid=seq(100), a=runif(100), b=runif(100, .5, 1.5))
```

I can create a plot comparing these two things like this (looks less funny given my real and better labels, but this does a good approximation):

```
ggplot(data=sample) + 
      geom_point(aes(rowid, a), color="#990000", alpha=0.4) +
      geom_smooth(aes(rowid, a), color='#990000') +
      geom_point(aes(rowid, b), color='#000099', alpha=0.4) +
      geom_smooth(aes(rowid, b), color='#000099') +
      labs(x='Trial', y='Time')
```

How can I get that to have a legend displaying what the red and the blue are?

**Edit**

Thanks to a comment from baptiste, I now have the following:

```
wide = melt(sample, id="rowid")

ggplot(data=wide) + 
      geom_point(aes(rowid, value, color=variable), alpha=0.1) +
      scale_alpha(0.3) +
      scale_colour_manual(name="Variables", values=c("b"="#990000", "a"="#000099")) +
      geom_smooth(aes(rowid, value, color=variable)) +
      labs(x='Trials', y='Time')
```

Comment: the idea is to work with a long format data.frame, such as `melt(sample, id="rowid")`. You can then do `aes(rowid, value, colour=variable)`

Comment: You pretty well answered my question, but I can't mark you as the winner.  :)  Although this seems a bit harer for me to control colors and alpha independently for my points and my lines.

Comment: Convincing is always about the 'right arguments' lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Baptiste pointed you in the right direction by suggesting using `melt` from the `reshape2` package.

To control the alpha of your points and smoother separately, simply specify the alpha you desire in each geom.  Note that the `scale_alpha` statement in your example code does nothing, because alpha was not mapped to any aesthetic, so I removed this.  Also, since your mapping is identical to all layers, this is easier to specify in the `ggplot` paramaters rather than the geom parameters:

```
sample <- data.frame(rowid=seq(100), a=runif(100), b=runif(100, .5, 1.5))
wide = melt(sample, id="rowid")

ggplot(data=wide, aes(x=rowid, y=value, color=variable)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.1) +
    scale_colour_manual(name="Variables", values=c("b"="#990000", "a"="#000099")) +
    geom_smooth(alpha=0.8) +
    labs(x='Trials', y='Time')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  You solved the rest of my problems and gave me some much needed tips.